# android Activity onPause - off Timer

Tags: java, android

I make an application for android and it has a timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTaskLoad timerTask = new TimerTaskLoad();
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 2 * 1000);


class TimerTaskLoad extends TimerTask {
@Override
public void run() {
// code
}
}
```

On my phone everything works. On some phones, the timer off when there is an onPause Activity.

How do I check whether the timer? And if not, turn it on again.